# Interpolation using multiple neighboring points

Tags: interpolation

I am wondering, what is a better way to do an interpolation based on 4 points neighborhood with knowing their value and distance.

Here is the illustration:

[image]

I'd like to know the value of the x. I know the valueof the four neighboring o being v0, v1, v2, v3, and I know their distance to x is d0, d1, d2, d3. So what is the good way to perform the interpolation to get x?

For example: I can do linear interpolation with v0 and v2 to estimate x. So can I do a better job (more likely estimate) by using all four points?

I can simply do a inverse of the distance, then normalize each one. It pretty much the idea of barry centric. Are there any high-order way (computationally inexpensive) to do it? For example, spline is probably not a good way from a computational point of view.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Doesn't sounds like you've done any research.  There's a wealth of published academia regarding mathematics. Maybe start with:
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting  And "best" is not a mathematically rigorous term.  The most you can get is what you ask for.  You need to ask for something specific.  What are the constraints?  What are your requirements?  What is the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Inverse distance weighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distance_weighting) strategy can work.